# How to use Apple SpeechSynthesis AudioUnit with AudioKit?

Tags: ios, audiokit

I was reading the book "Learning core audio". Then, I found this awesome library called **AudioKit**. :-) Everything works great until I want to use **Apple SpeechSynthesis AudioUnit**.

I searched through github repo, but I cannot find an AKNode for Speech Synthesis . Did I missing something?

I found some swift examples from [searching kAudioUnitSubType_SpeechSynthesis on github](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=kAudioUnitSubType_SpeechSynthesis&type=Code)

So I have two questions now:

1. How to add an **Apple AudioUnit Node** into **AudioKit** Graph?
2. Is there a reason that AudioKit doesn't support Speech Synthesis Node? Will AudioKit accept a PR for this?

Comment: Apple has released a tutorial in 2022: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/audio_units/creating_a_custom_speech_synthesizer?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to have a speech synthesizer in AudioKit, but as far as I know Apple doesn't let you hook it up to an audio processing graph.  However, if you do figure out how to make it work, the whole AudioKit core team would be delighted.  We would definitely accept a PR.

Comment: I created an AKSpeechSynthesizer Node and connected it to AudioKit. It speaks ~~~~~~~ 
But I started to learn swift two weeks ago... so it's too hard for me to make it as production ready code. Could you help? I will make a PR with a running example.

Comment: @WANGCHOULU Hella cool! Thanks, I'll look it over and help get it to completion.

Comment: @WANGCHOULU Take a look at the Develop branch of AudioKit.  I've added an example project in Examples/macOS/SpeechSynthesizer/ - the only issue is that it acts very strange, with the parameters like rate and pitch not able to be changed smoothly.  I've compared my work with the project you gave the URL for and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Everyone interested can continue to follow this story here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716391/why-cant-i-control-the-apple-macos-speech-synthesis-audio-unit-with-slider-valu

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16 and macOS Ventura you can now do this with AVSpeechSynthesisProviderAudioUnit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avspeechsynthesisprovideraudiounit

Here's a twitter thread about it https://twitter.com/ElaghaMosab/status/1560067672334733312

Comment: CC @aurelius-prochazka